# How do I remove toggle bolt from under the sink?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I am in the process of replacing my powder room faucet and I noticed that its not attached the normal way with a mounting nut.

I have what I assume is a toggle bolt holding the faucet in place, but I can't figure out how to remove it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: under the sink]
[image: another angle]

Answer (score 3):

Not toggle bolts. Just nuts with bushings and a crossbars under them (one of which has fallen into the sink bore, giving it the appearance of a toggler). Remove them in that order.

Comment: Isherwood is correct, It may be difficult if the nut is corroded. Spray it with PB Blaster penetrant. I recently had that very issue and i had to use a pair of locking pliers, vise grips, to pinch the barrel bushing tight enough to keep the stud from twisting while i worked the nut off. Then twist the pinched barrel off. OR if the nut is fused it may turn the threaded rod out of the faucet?  WEAR SAFETY GLASSES.